# How to show image in custom email. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, frontend, backend

I'm getting my **custom** data from email function and also I'm getting the **Product image URL** to show it in mail now I tried many ways to show my image in email but its not working for me my custom email code is

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} 
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Name:</b> {{trans "%name" name=$name}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Email:</b> {{trans "%email" email=$email}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Phone Number:</b> {{trans "%pnumber" pnumber=$pnumber}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Offer Amount:</b> {{trans "%offeramount" offeramount=$offeramount}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Message:</b> {{trans "%message" message=$message}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Product Name:</b> {{trans "%product_name" product_name=$product_name}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Product Price:</b> {{trans "%product_price" product_price=$product_price}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">URL:</b> {{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}}</p>
 <!-- <img src="">{{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}}</img> -->
 <!-- <img src="{{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}}"> -->
 <img src="{{view url='%imgUrl'}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

I get the code from net which is

```
    <img
     width="180"
     height="52"
     src="{{view url='images/email/youtube.jpg'}}"
     alt="Website Youtube"
 />
```

but now my question is how can I set **Dynamic** URL in place of fixed URL e.g in place of this URL **images/email/youtube.jpg** I want to set my URL

Comment: From wherever your email is been triggered after any action in controller you might be passing some variables just pass your email  url also in email vars and consume them. For reference you can open any default Magento email templates.

Comment: Sir I also pass the url as well if you can see this code {{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}} in above code that is URL which I firstly just print in <p> to check that URL is coming properly or not after that I tried this for <img> tag but at that place it is not working

Comment: Try src = "{{ imgUrl}}"

Comment: Are you.trying from your local ? Make sure you don't have any issue in showing images in every email ?

Comment: Sir Actually firstly when I get the URL of the product then firstly I check it in phtml file for testing that is it getting the img of the product or not.. then its shows me the img perfectly after that I send the URL in the mail

Comment: Okay. Issue resolved or not ??

Comment: Sir its still not working.. as you can see in the above code at which I just show the URL it shows me URL perfectly but I cannot fix it in <img>

Comment: Hope the variable in which you are getting url in email html file is : imgUrl. Did you tried <img src={{ imgUrl }}/ >. Can you please check if it works for you.

Comment: Sir Its still not Working

Comment: Don't know what's wrong you can check core Magento email templates. I faced a similar issue in which images were not shown if sending from local and was.working when send from live server. Also you can check printing url in a p tag in image src also it is just a variable.

Comment: @AsadKhan, do you want to add new column and want to show product image ?

Comment: @Pawan Sir I want to show Product Image which URL I get from my Email Class as you as you can see above {{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}} this is my URL now firstly I check it in <p> tag to check that is the URL is comming or not after that I use it in <img> tag but it is not working in < img> tag how can I set it in <img src="??">